# Is there any better way to implement hitbox/hurtbox system in godot platformer?

Tags: godot

let say I want to create an enemy that deal damage to player when touch and can receive damage from player (like Hollow Knight).

Here my current solution

1. Create `hitbox` at the player's weapon.
2. Create `hurtbox` at enemy's body
3. Create `hitbox` at enemy's body
4. Create `hurtbox` at player's body

If I use this method, every enemy will have to check 3 collision (2 Area2D and itself Character2D). Which I think it too much (I concerned about performance), enemy `hitbox` and `hurtbox` are usually the same shape anyway.

I have an idea to merge them, but isn't that anti-pattern? And I plan to have enemies that `hitbox` isn't the same shape as `hurtbox`.

Is there any better solution? I'm quite new to godot.

Comment: your box placements seem correct and there's usually no feasible way around collision detection but luckily Godot abstracts away that complication using [`Area2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_area2d.html) (reference for [3.5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQyyD-ykAHU) and [4.x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFKtAkeX0lg)), try writing the logic inside the hurtbox that if a hitbox enters it then reduce player health etc, it shouldn't be much complex

Comment: @M.R.M. So, I don't need to worry about performance or complexity of the node tree?

Comment: Nope that's a headache for the game engine, unless you're adding massive number of nodes (so many that you visually start seeing lags and stutters in your game), until then focus on learning first you can always optimise your code later